# Even extensions of d'Alembert's formula

Tags: partial-differential-equations

The task is to show that $V(0,t)=0$ where
\begin{equation}
    V(x,t)=\frac{1}{2}\Big(F(x+ct)+F(x-ct)\Big)+\frac{1}{2c}\int^{x+ct}_{x-ct}G(s)ds,
\end{equation}
with $F$ and $G$ both being defined to be even functions, that is, $F(x)=F(-x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

---

So far this is how I've got on$$V(0,t)=\frac{1}{2}\Big(F(ct)+F(-ct)\Big)+\frac{1}{2c}\int^{ct}_{-ct}G(s)ds, \tag1$$

then, I establish that the integral of an even function is odd by the following (I think)
$$\int^{y}_{0}G(y)dy=\int^{y}_{0}G(-y)dy=-\int^{-y}_{0}G(u)du=-G(-x),$$
and so, I can get rid of the integral in $(1)$, however I am a bit stumped with the $F$ part, tried coming up with some neat little integral for it too, but can't quite manage it. A hint would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Turns out there was a typo in the sheet. Question is meant to be show that $V_x(0,t)=0$.

Comment: Maybe try with a specific solution first, say $F(s)= e^{-|s|}$ and $G(s)$ it's derivative.  That's just an eyeball guess of a solution; it might not even work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The claim is false. Let $F(x) = G(x) \equiv 1$. These are even functions and you can compute that $$V(0,t) = 1 + t,$$ which is nonzero. However, the claim is true if $F$ and $G$ are *odd* functions.

Comment: That's what I was wondering too, have been stuck on this a while and haven't managed to manipulate it to a result that's desired. Will have to clarify with my lecturer, feel as though he may have made a typo then. Thanks!